# Read significance

Tags: r, statistical-significance, anova

I have a data file containg data like this. Here the angle can be seen as the severity of damage for all the species.

[image: example of data]

Now I did an Anova to see which factors are significant.

```r
    lm1 <- lmer(angle ~ erosion+flowspeed+species+erosion:species+flowspeed:species+(1|ID)).
```

Resulting in this:

```r
     Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
    erosion           323.3951  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
    flowspeed           9.8019  1   0.001743 ** 
    species            37.9759  2  5.671e-09 ***
    erosion:species   144.3583  2  < 2.2e-16 ***
    flowspeed:species   2.0618  2   0.356681
```

If I remove erosion however ...

```r
    lm2 <- lmer(angle ~ flowspeed+species+flowspeed:species+(1|ID)))
```

... flowspeed:species is suddenly significant:

```r
      Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
    flowspeed         47.827  1  4.656e-12 ***
    species           37.804  2  6.180e-09 ***
    flowspeed:species 13.379  2   0.001244 **
```

Can I say there is a significant interaction between flowspeed and species or do I have to look at the most complete ANOVA?
[image: A graph of the dataset]
If I want to keep the erosion as factor is there anyway I can can statistically show that the almost straight line of S. tabernaemontani  at a flow velocity of 0 m/s is statisticaly significantly different to the other species.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you remove an important covariate like `erosion`, *you completely change the meaning of the regression.* It is therefore no surprise that estimates for other variables change and their p-values change.  What it comes down to, then, is whether you want to interpret a model that ignores the associations with `erosion` or one that accounts for it.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for answering I just added a graph to the question. In this graph S. tabernaemontani is almost straight at a flow velocity of 0 m/s. Do you by any chance a way I can statistically show this is a significant difference?

Comment: That's an interesting case because the error variance is noticeably smaller than for the other species-flow regimes.  It would be best, though, to take this difference as a *hypothesis* discovered from these data and use independent data to test your hypothesis.

Comment: Very interesting graph! In the absence of flow, the plants are much less sensitive to erosion, in particular S. tabernaemontani, that bends very strongly with high erosion depth when there is flow. Do you have a biological explanation? Like shallow rooting? Ideally, as @whuber suggests, you'd have a second dataset to test. It is otherwise a bit of a cheat. Is it possible for you to share the original data?

Comment: Btw, how do you measure angle?